# How did Ginny get out of the ring of fire during 'The Burning of the Burrow'?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-half-blood-prince

In *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, when Bellatrix encircled the Weasleys' house with a ring of fire, that's how the events took place

1. The Burrow gets encircled with the ring of fire (with a small opening in it).
2. Bellatrix Apparates in front of the door and ran out of the ring from that opening (mentioned above).
3. Harry comes down and then out of the house and follows Bellatrix.
4. Lupin and Tonks run after Harry to stop him but fail to do so when the ring (of fire) closes behind Harry.
5. Lupin and Tonks try to fight (or control) the ring when Ginny comes running out of the house.
6. The ring presents an opening again and lets Ginny cross it (presumably leaving behind the others i.e. Lupin, Tonks and Weasley parents to control the fire).

Why did the ring of fire open itself for Ginny, when the main purpose of the attack seems only to get Harry out of the safety zone?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think ring specifically opened up for Ginny. She just jumped out of it at an instant when Lupin and Tonks were trying to create an opening.

Comment: For a moment if we consider this to be true, it still seems a bit strange to me because if the opening was created by Lupin and Tonks then it was only Ginny who was able to use it and not those who created it in the first place. The opening closed behind her and they continued to control the ring of fire.

Comment: @CCCC: If you observe carefully, opening was not trying to close. It was like two tentacles of fire which were trying to grab anyone ( other than Harry )  tries to pass through it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if Ginny took the opportunity while Lupin and Tonks were trying to control the fire and jumped over it, that's all.